# Replace only single blank with empty sting but keep multiple blanks

Tags: python, regex

For example:

I can't use `re.sub(r' ', '', content)`. Because I want to keep multiple continual blanks, only replace isolated single blank to empty string.

I know how to match the single blank by `[^ ]( )[^ ]`

But it would also match left and right:

[regex 101 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTnl1.png)

I know I can do something like

```
re.sub(r'  +', '$$$$$', content)
re.sub(r' ', '', content)
re.sub(r'$$$$$', '     ', content)
```

But I wonder is there any easy way to achieve my goal?

---

Thanks to  @Wiktor Stribiżew , the first one works

```
In [2]: content = "ss ss   sss ddd rrt        d d dd     "

In [3]: re.sub(r'(?<! ) (?! )', '', content)
Out[3]: 'ssss   sssdddrrt        dddd     '

In [4]: re.sub(r'( ) ( )', r'\1\2', content)
Out[4]: 'ss ss  sss ddd rrt      d d dd    '
```

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(?<! ) (?! )', '', content)`. Or `re.sub(r'( ) ( )', r'\1\2', content)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  The first one works, could you explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(?<! ) (?! )', '', content)
```

Or, to handle any whitespace:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\s)\s(?!\s)', '', content)
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/a3I2dC/1).

To match a single occurrence not enclosed with the same chars you need a lookbehind/lookahead based approach like above.

The `(?<! )` makes sure there is no space immediately to the left of the current location, and `(?! )` makes sure there is no space immediately to the right of the current location.